# Is there rendaku in 感動話?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings, rendaku

In this sentence

感動話は“感動【かんどう】”と書【か】かずにいかに心【こころ】が震【ふる】えたかを伝【つた】えよ

*Don't use the word "moving" to describe a touching story, but tell how your heart was shaken.*

https://www.asahi.com/and/article/20220921/422524333/

..-is the reading of "touching story" ...

感動話【かんどうはなし】 or  感動話【かんどうばなし】 or  感動話【かんどうわ】 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's かんどうばなし because it refers to touching stories in general. Rendaku is necessary.

(感動話 is read かんどうわ when if refers to an episode of a serial drama, manga, anime, etc. [Example](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11242262606))